# EXIF Orientation field is empty on Android photos

Tags: java, android, image-processing, exif

I need to rotate images if needed at the server side. I used metadata-extractor package and apache commons-imaging for this purposes, but for some photos taken on Android I can't get any orientation field values with java, but any exif metadata reader sites can.

For example:

https://imgbbb.com/image/LVtrUD -- image

And it's metadata extracted with Apache Imaging.

```
11.10.2019 14:55:35.825 INFO  [http-bio-8080-exec-11] **.utils.ExifImageUtils:44 - ORIENTATION 0
[JPEG] - Compression Type = Baseline
[JPEG] - Data Precision = 8 bits
[JPEG] - Image Height = 2448 pixels[JPEG] - Image Width = 3264 pixels
[JPEG] - Number of Components = 3
[JPEG] - Component 1 = Y component: Quantization table 0, Sampling factors 2 horiz/2 vert
[JPEG] - Component 2 = Cb component: Quantization table 1, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert
[JPEG] - Component 3 = Cr component: Quantization table 1, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert
[JFIF] - Version = 1.1
[JFIF] - Resolution Units = inch
[JFIF] - X Resolution = 72 dots
[JFIF] - Y Resolution = 72 dots
[JFIF] - Thumbnail Width Pixels = 0
[JFIF] - Thumbnail Height Pixels = 0
[Exif IFD0] - Make = samsung
[Exif IFD0] - Model = SM-T585
[Exif IFD0] - X Resolution = 72 dots per inch
[Exif IFD0] - Y Resolution = 72 dots per inch
[Exif IFD0] - Resolution Unit = Inch
[Exif IFD0] - Software = T585XXU5CSB1
[Exif IFD0] - Date/Time = 2019:09:12 09:28:02
[Exif IFD0] - YCbCr Positioning = Center of pixel array
[Exif SubIFD] - Exposure Time = 1/33 sec
[Exif SubIFD] - F-Number = f/1.9
[Exif SubIFD] - Exposure Program = Program normal
[Exif SubIFD] - ISO Speed Ratings = 160
[Exif SubIFD] - Exif Version = 2.20
[Exif SubIFD] - Date/Time Original = 2019:09:12 09:28:02
[Exif SubIFD] - Date/Time Digitized = 2019:09:12 09:28:02
[Exif SubIFD] - Components Configuration = YCbCr
[Exif SubIFD] - Shutter Speed Value = 1/33 sec
[Exif SubIFD] - Aperture Value = f/1.9
[Exif SubIFD] - Brightness Value = 1.55
[Exif SubIFD] - Exposure Bias Value = 0 EV
[Exif SubIFD] - Max Aperture Value = f/1.9
[Exif SubIFD] - Metering Mode = Center weighted average
[Exif SubIFD] - Flash = Flash did not fire
[Exif SubIFD] - Focal Length = 2.9 mm
[Exif SubIFD] - Makernote = [98 values]
[Exif SubIFD] - User Comment = 
[Exif SubIFD] - Sub-Sec Time = 0731
[Exif SubIFD] - Sub-Sec Time Original = 0731
[Exif SubIFD] - Sub-Sec Time Digitized = 0731
[Exif SubIFD] - FlashPix Version = 1.00
[Exif SubIFD] - Color Space = sRGB
[Exif SubIFD] - Exif Image Width = 3264 pixels
[Exif SubIFD] - Exif Image Height = 2448 pixels
[Exif SubIFD] - Exposure Mode = Auto exposure
[Exif SubIFD] - White Balance Mode = Auto white balance
[Exif SubIFD] - Focal Length 35 = 27 mm
[Exif SubIFD] - Scene Capture Type = Standard
[Exif SubIFD] - Unique Image ID = J08LLJA00AM J08LLLJ01AA
[Interoperability] - Interoperability Index = Recommended Exif Interoperability Rules (ExifR98)
[Interoperability] - Interoperability Version = 1.00
[Exif Thumbnail] - Image Width = 512 pixels
[Exif Thumbnail] - Image Height = 384 pixels
[Exif Thumbnail] - Compression = JPEG (old-style)
[Exif Thumbnail] - Orientation = Unknown (0)
[Exif Thumbnail] - X Resolution = 72 dots per inch
[Exif Thumbnail] - Y Resolution = 72 dots per inch
[Exif Thumbnail] - Resolution Unit = Inch
[Exif Thumbnail] - Thumbnail Offset = 1008 bytes
[Exif Thumbnail] - Thumbnail Length = 33822 bytes
[Huffman] - Number of Tables = 4 Huffman tables
[File Type] - Detected File Type Name = JPEG
[File Type] - Detected File Type Long Name = Joint Photographic Experts Group
[File Type] - Detected MIME Type = image/jpeg
[File Type] - Expected File Name Extension = jpg
[File] - File Name = 1.jpg
[File] - File Size = 3834043 bytes
[File] - File Modified Date = Fri Oct 11 14:55:34 +03:00 2019
```

Is it possible to get correct orientation field value?

Comment: And what is the rotation according these metadata readers?

Comment: So the website does not show the image ok.In landscape.  I downloaded the image and WIndows shows it like te website does. Are there any image viewer that show th epicture in portrait mode.

Comment: Indeed there is rotation infpormation as my Android viewer shows it in portrait mode.

Comment: Irfanview shows it in landscape too and sais: Filename - to-rotate.jpg
Make - samsung
Model - SM-T585

Orientation - Right top. Whatever that means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved my problem using ExifTool (https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) and Java Wrapper on it (https://github.com/rkalla/exiftool)